# Javascript / Amchart adjusting categoryFiled and color

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am trying to replicate this [graph](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/3d-cylinder-chart/) from amcharts and we are in the plan of purchasing the license if everything suits our needs. We are facing two issues at the moment.

1. I see in the data provider color is provided, i am providing the json data as an input here. But in the json, we won't be able to add the color. Is there any other ways to include those colors somewhere else ?

> "dataProvider": [{
>           "country": "USA",
>           "visits": 4025,
>           "color": "#FF0F00"
>       }, {
>           "country": "China",
>           "visits": 1882,
>           "color": "#FF6600"
>       }]

2. The name of the categoryField is quite lengthy and so we want to make it to slanding like this --> [Slanding Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgQXY.png). How can we achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - No. Coloring individual columns need to happen inside your data as it's using the [`fillColorsField`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#fillColorsField) property to find the color in each element in the dataProvider array. There isn't another way to do this. You can try modifying your JSON after the fact in JavaScript and add those colors in before assigning it to AmCharts' dataProvider.

2 - Set [`labelRotation`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#labelRotation) in the category axis.

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ...
  categoryAxis: {
    labelRotation: 45,
    // ...
  },
  // ...
})
```

Comment: do you mind providing an example for adding colors filed to the json data using javascript ? For example, i have defined a variable x which holds the json data without color field. Now I need to add colors to the variable x.

Comment: Assuming your graph's `fillColorsField` is set to "color": `x.forEach(function(jsonElement) { jsonElement.color = /* set a color here */; });`. I don't know what logic you're applying to determine what color goes into a particular element, so you'll have to figure that one out yourself.

Comment: I have tried something like this https://codepen.io/gknathkumar/pen/mBzEdQ but it doesn't work. Could you shed some pointers ?

Comment: It looks like your JS knowledge is a bit lacking, so I recommend brushing up first. 1 - Color needs to be a string and only *one* color. 2 - forEach is a loop, so this logic would be setting a list of colors to every element, which is wrong. Also forEach doesn't return a value, it modifies x directly, so `var y` is wrong. 3 - you need to set up logic that determines which element in the array gets which color, so you could possibly use an if or switch/case for each possible country. [Fixed version](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/7bdd8edc997b4525bb909728c0afcb22/). Compare against yours.